# Unsure if website has been hacked with iframe

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe

My website seems to be loading code which doesn't actually exist on my server. I know the problem is server-side because I've tested with other computers...

The code seems to load a header and then put's my real website inside an iframe, strangely there are no ads or redirects which I would have expected from a hack.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="description" content="our real website">
<meta name="keywords" content="our real website">
<title>our real website</title>
</head>
<body style="border:0;font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;font-style:inherit;font-weight:inherit;margin:0;outline:0;padding:0;vertical-align:baseline;">
<iframe src="http://our real website.com/beta" style="width:100%; height:100%; border:none !important; margin:0px !important; padding:0px !important;"/>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what chrome and firefox's "show source" gives me.

I have made sure the files on the server don't contain any mention of iframes. I have also tested by creating a new empty sub directory with a blank index file but when I open it up in a browser I get the same iframe stuff! This makes me strongly suspect my server is hacked.

What can I do in this situation?

Thanks

Comment: "Show Source" shows the original HTML. The hacker must've modified the page after it was loaded. Try clicking "Inspect Element." Anything suspicious?

Comment: Apache in some way pre-process or post-process the request. So you see all things "normal" on folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops!

Turns out my domain provider (seperate to my web host) had enabled forwarding "with cloaking" and this caused my site to be shown in an iframe.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Your domain provider should let you know when they do stuff like that because it can make a huge negative SEO impact on the website.

Comment: No problem, I wish I could've helped more.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a hack alright.

Apart from what Narawa said in the comment, try also the incognito mode, connect from a different IP, use different browsers - sometimes they're smart enough to run/show malware only on the first run on a machine. Then they probably store a cookie or localStorage data in order not to show it again. See if anything different happens in different modes, browsers and computers. Try seeing your site the way Google bot sees it (there's an option in their Webmaster Tools).

Also check server logs, see when the files were modified, compare it with your backup, check the .htaccess file, if you can, try running the website on another server, etc...

---

To fix it, you could simply restore a working backup, but that's not a good idea since it means the attack can be repeated the same way. That's why I mentioned all the ideas in the first paragraph - make sure you know as much as you can about the attack, see which part of your website is vulnerable, then patch that first, and restore the backup later.

Comment: it's possible to injecting html from client side, just like browser addons?

Comment: Yes, and it's quite simple to do using JavaScript. That's why the potential malicious code doesn't show up when you view source, but might be there when you inspect the DOM afterwards. It's important to see where they gained control.

Comment: downvoter just think they have` lot reputation to expend`, just leave comment and downvote, my question got downvote 4 times, cause not show the code, after showing the code the just leave and not upvote

Comment: @ntaloventi Yeah, unfortunately that happens every now and then to everybody, and sometimes it even makes me forget about the **numerous great people** we have here on SO.